# Which format is the PKCS12 successor?

Tags: pkcs12

The [documentation of a PKCS12 implementation for Go](https://godoc.org/software.sslmate.com/src/go-pkcs12) states the following:

> It is intended for decoding P12/PFX files for use with the crypto/tls package, and for encoding P12/PFX files for use by legacy applications which do not support newer formats. Since PKCS#12 uses weak encryption primitives, it SHOULD NOT be used for new applications.

I am wondering: which are the new formats succeeding PKCS12?

Comment: It's true that p12 use weak crypto (which seems to have been borrowed by java keystores, btw). I'm also curious what you're supposed to use instead.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://sslmate.com/help/cmdline/config) from the source of your citation (sslmate.org) defaults to the use of chained, [PEM encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail), certificates. This is a [common alternative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12) to PKCS#12, because of its ease of use.

The justification "Since PKCS#12 uses weak encryption primitives" is incorrect in the sense that the alternative does not encrypt its content. However, usually PKCS#12 data is encrypted using a default password for its key, which does not provide more security than PEM encoded data.

Comment: A chain of certificates is not an alternative to PKCS12, because PKCS12 is a container format, which also does contain something different than certificates: a private key.

Comment: @ceving You usually find the private key encoded in the PEM format with its associated certificate (containing the public key) appended to it, also encoded in PEM. The PEM format makes it trivially easy to append as many keys (public or private) as you wish.